# How do I get the "auth_code" from location key in the request header?

Tags: python, python-requests, robotframework, requests-oauthlib

I am using a combination of the Robot request library, Python requests library and the Python requests_oauthlib library for the testing of an OAuth2 project.

I wonder if there is an easy way to grab the auth code (without string indexing) so I can use it in generating a token

So for example, I have the response header (from logging in):

```
{'location': 'http://127.0.0.1:19333/callback?code=clT17dFPedsgdfgsSFGDF%3D%3D&state=random%2F', 'content-length': '0', 'date': 'Fri, 09 Oct 2020 11:20:52 GMT'}
```

which I got by doing `response.header`

Is there some way I can just get the `clT17dFPedsgdfgsSFGDF%3D%3D`  by doing something like `request.auth_code`

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Urllib.parse`. The `parse_qs` function returns a dictionary of key-value pairs whereas the `parse_qsl` function returns a list of (key, value) tuples.

```
import urllib.parse
queryStr = 'http://127.0.0.1:19333/callback?code=clT17dFPedsgdfgsSFGDF%3D%3D&state=random%2F'
urllib.parse.parse_qsl(queryStr)
```

**Output -**

[image]

For more details on [URL encoding](https://www.urldecoder.io/python/)

Comment: In "robot speak" - `Evaluate    urllib.parse.parse_qsl($queryStr)    urllib` ;)